# How to display a popup behind a popup?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, frontend

I was just curious to know about creating a popup which generates another popup BEHIND it, whenever a button is clicked.

Let me explain more:

I have a button `Bu` in the main window.

When I click this button, a popup say `Pop_a` with a button `Bu_a` should appear.

When I click button `Bu_a` a popup `Pop_b` should be opened, but behind `Pop_a`.

Comment: Just set the Panel.ZIndex property on your popups accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In `Pop_a`, within the button click handler, call `this.Activate()` after the line that shows the `Pop_b` window.

It should look something like this.

```
public partial class Pop_a : Window
{
    public Pop_a()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Bu_a_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pop_b = new Pop_b();

        pop_b.Show();

        this.Activate();
    }
}
```

This will put `Pop_a` back on top of all other windows, after `Pop_b` has been shown.

If you call `this.Activate()` before calling `pop_b.Show()`,  `Pop_a` will be put on top, and then `Pop_b` will be shown, which puts `Pop_b` on top, so the order of these method calls matters. Show new window, then Activate the window you want on top.

Comment: That supposes he's not using the `MessageBox`, but yes, it would work. It's noteworthy that the 2nd window wouldn't be kept behind, but it might be what the OP wants.

Comment: What if I don't want to have 2 windows? I want the same to be happening in the same window.